# Nginx: How to custom error page depends on presence of custom http header

Tags: nginx

we are using nginx as reverse http proxy before tomcat. Our app can return  different HTTP status codes (400, 401, 404, 403) depends on requests. Every response from our app return custom HTTP header, let's say X-Custom which is used to determine if app is working and serving the request.

Our goal on nginx side is to serve custom error pages generated by our app to the client in case when custom HTTP header X-Custom is present and otherwise (if X-Custom is not present) serve our custom static page from nginx.

The problem is, I am not able to find out working solution even I tried almost everything. I am sure that I am missing something obvious.

Nginx configuration looks like:

```
    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port   80;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  https;

        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;

        proxy_intercept_errors on;
        proxy_pass http://172.16.0.32:8080;

        if ($is_x_custom_not_ok = "No") {
            error_page 400 401 404 403 500 502 503 /503.html;
        }
    }
```

```
map $upstream_http_x_custom $is_x_custom_not_ok {
    default "No";
    ~. "Yes";
}
```

```
location /503.html {
        root /var/www/;
        internal;
        }
```

This is causing that even if header X-Custom is present and app return HTTP 400, static 503.html is shown. 503.html should be loaded only in case when X-Custom is not present in response.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So, after endless hours I figured out that this is not going to work. The reason is, that the `map` and `if` blocks are executed **before** passing the upstream (proxy), so map and neither if does not have the x-custom content when they are executed.

So, my solution is to use Nginx OpenResty Lua to examine my custom header and make a decision on what error page to display.